# Android imageview cut off on phone

Tags: android, xml, imageview

in the xml graphic layout everything looks fine but on the phone a peace gets cut-off anyone know why, been at it for hours?

graphic layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbg5u.png

on phone:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AyOl.png

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<EditText
    android:id="@id/klacht"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/send"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/email"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/naam"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/naam"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
    android:text="Naam: " />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/email"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/klacht"
    android:text="Email: " />

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tflogo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Je bent niet verplicht je naam in te vullen als je anoniem wilt blijven. Vergeet niet je e-mail te vermelden als je een terugkoppeling wilt." />

<Button
    android:id="@id/send"
    android:layout_width="150.0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Verstuur" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/naam"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/klacht"
    android:layout_below="@id/naam"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Als je terugkoppeling wilt"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/naam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="18.0dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Niet verplicht"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/tflogosub" />
```

Comment: Which phone are you trying at? Is the phones dpi set to the dpi in  your IDE's (Eclipse or Studio) graphical layout when viewing your xml file?

Comment: Do you have different images for different screen resolutions? (as in drawable, drawable-hdpi) etc..? Maybe you have the wrong image in one of those folders?

Comment: Make sure you are using right images for all drawable types.